# Azure KeyVault Enable or disable secret key from c#

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I have been looking at an option to enable the secret key in the key vault from C# with managed identity.
I have full permissions and I am able to create, delete and change the secrets but somehow, if I create a disabled secret key, I cannot read that to re-enable it.
Could anyone help to know whether it is possible to enable the disabled key from c#?

Comment: You could update the `Enabled` in SecretProperties of secret, refer to the [SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.security.keyvault.secrets.secretclient.updatesecretproperties?view=azure-dotnet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add my comment as an answer:

You could update the Enabled in SecretProperties of secret, refer to the [SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.security.keyvault.secrets.secretclient.updatesecretproperties?view=azure-dotnet).

```
var kvUri = "https://" + keyVaultName + ".vault.azure.net";
var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(kvUri), new DefaultAzureCredential());

KeyVaultSecret secret = client.GetSecret("secret-name");
secret.Properties.Enabled = true;
SecretProperties updatedSecretProperties = client.UpdateSecretProperties(secret.Properties);

Console.WriteLine(updatedSecretProperties.Enabled);
```

For more details, you could see [the official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/security.keyvault.secrets-readme-pre#update-an-existing-secret).

Answer (score 0):

Without getting the secret, if you know the name you can simply update it's properties:

```cs
var client = new SecretClient(
  new Uri("https://myvault.vault.azure.net"),
  new DefaultAzureCredential());

await client.UpdateSecretPropertiesAsync(
  new SecretProperties("secret-name")
  {
    Enabled = true,
  });
```

If you already have a `KeyVaultSecret`, set it's `Properties.Enabled` to true and pass `Properties` to the same method above.