# How do I specify properties for a Azure Key Vault Secret from a Function App?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-functions, azure-keyvault

I'm trying to create an Azure Function that creates a secret in a Key Vault with an expiration time of 30 minutes from now.

Just creating a secret with no properties works without any issues:

```cs
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;

namespace Company.Function
{
    public static class Save
    {
        [FunctionName("save")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {

            var client = new SecretClient(
                new Uri("https://<my-vault>.vault.azure.net/"), 
                new DefaultAzureCredential()
            );

            var secret = await client.SetSecretAsync("name", "value");

            return new OkObjectResult("Done");
        }
    }
}
```

*(Access is set up by enabling a system-assigned identity and granting that access to write secrets to the Key Vault)*

Ideally, I would like to do one request that includes both setting the secret and its properties but I can't find documentation for that in C#.

I've tried adding this code, but it fails with a message that `Version` can't be `null`:

```cs
var props = new SecretProperties(data.repo);
props.ExpiresOn = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(30);
await client.UpdateSecretPropertiesAsync("name");
```

Any idea what I'm missing? I've looked at a [bunch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65727387/azure-keyvault-enable-or-disable-secret-key-from-c-sharp) [of](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.security.keyvault.secrets.secretproperties?view=azure-dotnet) [pages](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1430794/Using-Csharp-NET-to-Read-and-Write-from-Azure-Key) without finding a solution.

Comment: _"that **creates** a secret in a Key Vault with an expiration time of 30 minutes from now."_ - uhm, **why**? Usually application code is simply a _consumer_ of secrets...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use this different overload of SetSecretAsync:

```cs
var secret = new KeyVaultSecret("name", "value");
secret.Properties.ExpiresOn = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(30);
await client.SetSecretAsync(secret);
```

Comment: Such a simple solution once you know  Thank you so much!